# patron de animaciones en unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity

lo que intento hacer es que si los animators se ejecutan en un orden específico,(ej: primero el animator2, segundo el animator1, tercero el animator4, cuarto el animator3)haga algo.

me e perdido mucho con este problema y eh intentado de muchas maneras para corregirlo, pero nada dio éxito.

si es necesario pues lo que intento es que si en la siguiete imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siendo mas especifico lo que intento es que sea como un "patron" o "orden" no se como llamarlo la verdad.

quiero que si presionas el boton superior izquierdo, luego el inferior izquierdo; el inferior derecho; y por ultimo el superior derecho se instancie un objeto.

cada uno tiene su animator, y todos tienen un parametro en específico, llamado "click", si le das click a cualquiera de estos 4 botones ocurra un cambio de color que es el que indica si esta presionado o no.

si quieren un poco mas de informacion por comentario gracias

Comment: En lugar de hacer algo en base a los animators, haz que los animators funcionen en base a algo. Supon que los activas con un clic. Ese código que detecta que lo cliqueaste se puede encargar de cambiar el estado del animator e informar a la parte correspondiente del código que fue activado. Por ejemplo, podrías guardar en un arreglo o una lista un número único para cada objeto en el orden que fueron presionados. Verificar que el orden es el deseado es fácil.

Comment: Al programar no hay una única solución. Así que intenta algo y carga el código porque sin código parece una petición para que hagamos tu trabajo.